# How do I fix (unsupported operand type(s) error)?

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, gurobi, heuristics

I am writing a meta-heuristic (PSO) using Gurobi for optimization and I am stuck at this problem where it says TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list' and I can't find what is wrong with it.

Here is the code:

```
import random
from turtle import color
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import gurobipy as grb
import time





# Fix Random Seed
random.seed(10)


# Function Returning Objective Value 
def COVID_19_Program(Logistic_Function_Parameters):

    K = Logistic_Function_Parameters[0][0]
    Q = Logistic_Function_Parameters[0][1]
    Lambda = Logistic_Function_Parameters[0][2]
    v = Logistic_Function_Parameters[0][3]
    
    COVID_19 = grb.Model(name = 'COVID-19 Optimization Model')

    # Data:

    # Ĉ
    C = [0, 7, 16, 23, 33, 42, 49, 55, 59, 63, 68, 72, 77, 81, 87, 90, 95, 100, 106, 112, 115, 119, 123, 127, 129, 132, 136, 140, 143, 145, 149, 152, 156, 160, 163, 166, 170, 174, 179, 183, 187, 192, 197, 201, 206, 210, 215, 218, 222, 227, 231, 234, 238, 243, 247, 252, 257, 260, 265, 271, 277, 282, 287, 291, 296, 301, 305, 311, 316, 322, 328, 333, 340, 344, 350, 355, 362, 368, 373, 379, 386]

    # Number of Days
    Days = len(C) - 1


    # τ
    Taomin = 11
    Taomax = 27


    # ζ
    Rmin = 10
    Rmode = 28
    Rmax = 40

    # Data Sets
    set_Time = range(1, Days + 1)
    set_Tao = range(1, Taomax + 1)
    set_Recovery = range(1, Rmax + 1)


    # Model 

    # I(t) Equations Number (1 & 2)
    def I(t, K, Q, Lambda, v):  
        return (K / (1 + Q * np.exp(-Lambda * t)) ** (1 / v))

    
    # N(t) Equations Number (3 & 4)
    def N(t, K, Q, Lambda, v):
        if t <= 0:
            return 0
        else:
            return I(t, K, Q, Lambda, v) - I(t - 1, K, Q, Lambda, v)
    

    # D.V: 

    # Error (ε)
    Epsilon = {t: COVID_19.addVar(vtype = grb.GRB.CONTINUOUS, lb = -1000000000, name = 'ε'.format(t)) for t in set_Time}

    # a 
    a = {j: COVID_19.addVar(vtype = grb.GRB.CONTINUOUS, lb = 0, name = 'alpha'.format(j)) for j in set_Tao}

    # b 
    b = {j: COVID_19.addVar(vtype = grb.GRB.CONTINUOUS, lb = 0, name = 'beta'.format(j)) for j in set_Recovery}


    
    # Constraints:
    
    # Constraint (17)
    constraints = {t: 
    COVID_19.addConstr(
            lhs = grb.quicksum(a[j]*N(k - j, K, Q, Lambda, v) for j in set_Tao if j >= Taomin for k in set_Time if k <= t),
            sense = grb.GRB.EQUAL,
            rhs = C[t] - Epsilon[t],
            name = 'Constraint_17'.format(t))
        for t in set_Time}
    

    # Constraint (18)
    constraints = COVID_19.addConstr(lhs = grb.quicksum(a[j] + b[k] for j in set_Tao if j >= Taomin for k in set_Recovery if k >= Rmin), sense = grb.GRB.EQUAL, rhs = 1, name = 'Constraint_18')


    # Constraint (19)
    constraints = {j: 
    COVID_19.addConstr(
            lhs = b[j - 1],
            sense = grb.GRB.LESS_EQUAL,
            rhs = b[j],
            name = 'Constraint_19'.format(j))
        for j in set_Recovery if j >= (Rmin + 1) and j <= Rmode}


    # Constraint (20)
    constraints = {j: 
    COVID_19.addConstr(
            lhs = b[j],
            sense = grb.GRB.GREATER_EQUAL,
            rhs = b[j + 1],
            name = 'Constraint_20'.format(j))
        for j in set_Recovery if j >= Rmode and j <= (Rmax - 1)}




    
    O_F = grb.quicksum(Epsilon[t]*Epsilon[t] for t in set_Time)


    COVID_19.setObjective((O_F))
    

    COVID_19.optimize()


    Objective_F_Value = COVID_19.ObjVal


    return Objective_F_Value


# K Values Generator
def K_Value_Randomizer():
    return random.randint(1000000, 35000000)


# Q Values Generator
def Q_Value_Randomizer():
    return random.randint(1, 10000)


# Lambda Values Generator
def Lambda_Value_Randomizer():
    return random.random()


# nu Values Generator
def v_Value_Randomizer():
    return random.uniform(0.0001, 2) 


# Generalized Logistic Function Bounds [K, Q, Lambda, nu]
Parameter_Bounds = [(1000000, 35000000), (1, 10000), (0, 1), (0.0001, 2)]
Number_of_Variables = 4 # K, Q, Lambda, nu


# PSO Paramters
Swarm_Size = 20 # Number of Particles in the Swarm
Iterations = 20 # Max Number of Iterations
w = 0.75 # Inertia Weight
c1 = 1 # Cognitive Factor
c2 = 2 # Social Factor


# Value for initial fitness
initial_fitness = float('inf')

# Best global position and fitness
global_best_particle_position = []
fitness_global_best_particle_position = initial_fitness

# Swarm
Swarm = []


# Visualization
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()
fig.show()


# Particle Class
class Particle:
    def __init__(self, Parameter_Bounds):
        self.particle_position = []
        self.particle_velocity = []
        self.local_best_particle_position = []
        self.fitness_particle_position = initial_fitness # Value of current particle position after calculating the objective function
        self.fitness_local_best_particle_position = initial_fitness # initial value of the particle's best position after calculating the objective function
        # Both lines 168 & 169 are used to fill the fitness values with an initial value

        # Fill Particle (K, Q, Lambda, nu) (Generate Random Initial (Position & Velocity))
        Parameter_List = [K_Value_Randomizer(), Q_Value_Randomizer(), Lambda_Value_Randomizer(), v_Value_Randomizer()]
        self.particle_position.append(Parameter_List)
        self.particle_velocity.append(Parameter_List)

    
    def evaluate(self, COVID_19_Program):
        self.fitness_particle_position = COVID_19_Program(self.particle_position)
        
        if self.fitness_particle_position < self.fitness_local_best_particle_position:
            self.local_best_particle_position = self.particle_position # Update the Position
            self.fitness_local_best_particle_position = self.fitness_particle_position # Update the Fitness
    

    
    def update_velocity(self, global_best_particle_position):
        for i in range(Number_of_Variables):
            r1 = random.random()
            r2 = random.random()

            Cognitive_Velocity = c1 * r1 * (self.local_best_particle_position[i] - self.particle_position[i])
            Social_Velocity = c2 * r2 * (global_best_particle_position[i] - self.particle_position[i])
            self.particle_velocity[i] = w * self.particle_velocity[i] + Cognitive_Velocity + Social_Velocity


    def update_position(self, Parameter_Bounds):
        for i in range(Number_of_Variables):
            self.particle_position[i] = self.particle_position[i] + self.particle_velocity[i]

            # Bounding 
            if self.particle_position[i] > Parameter_Bounds[i][1]:
                self.particle_position[i] = Parameter_Bounds[i][1]

            if self.particle_position[i] < Parameter_Bounds[i][0]:
                self.particle_position[i] = Parameter_Bounds[i][0]




# !@#$%^&*()

A = []

for i in range(Swarm_Size):
    Swarm.append(Particle(Parameter_Bounds))


for i in range(Iterations):
    for j in range(Swarm_Size):
        Swarm[j].evaluate(COVID_19_Program)

        if Swarm[j].fitness_particle_position < fitness_global_best_particle_position:
            global_best_particle_position = list(Swarm[j].particle_position)
            fitness_global_best_particle_position = float(Swarm[j].fitness_particle_position)
        
    for j in range(Swarm_Size):
        Swarm[j].update_velocity(global_best_particle_position)
        Swarm[j].update_position(Parameter_Bounds)


    A.append(fitness_global_best_particle_position) # Record the best fitness


    # Visualization
    ax.plot(A, color = 'r')
    fig.canvas.draw()
    ax.set_xlim(left = max(0, i - Iterations), right = i + 3)


print('Optimal Solution: ', global_best_particle_position)
print('Objective Function Value: ', fitness_global_best_particle_position)
plt.show()
```

It says it has to do something with Cognitive_Velocity variable but I fail to see why is it a problem.

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Comment: Whatever is at index 0 of the particle position must be a list, which cannot be subtracted from another list.